# Excel Data Validation Custom Formula: how to define alphanumeric formatting with defined character and digit placements

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm attempting to apply data validation to a particular cell's input.  The structure needs to be formatted as `@@##-######`, where @ = string and # = numbers.  I've attempted various custom formulas, but for some reason they are not working.  My first attempt was to define as

`=AND(ISTEXT(LEFT(C11,2)),ISNUMBER(AND(MID(C11,3,2),RIGHT(C11,6))))`

However, I'm not sure why this doesn't work, I'm guessing because there is string the remaining digits are being treated as text rather than numbers?

Next, I tried to modify an existing example I found online for a similar use case, only their structuring was different so I attempted to adapt it accordingly...

`=AND(ISTEXT(LEFT(C11,2)),SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--AND(MID(C11,3,2),RIGHT(C11,6)))=8))`

...except it still doesn't work.  This one I'm not fully conceptualizing how it works to begin with, so I'm not able to tell what's working or not and why.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

PS: I realize these don't consider the hyphen, I figured I'd get to that after figuring out the string & numbers first.

Comment: `AND(MID(C11,3,2),RIGHT(C11,6)) ` returns an error, as it's doing a logical AND on two strings. `(MID(C11,3,2)&RIGHT(C11,6))` returns the concatenation of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the LEFT and MID functions always return strings and even though there can technically be numbers in them, the ISNUMBER function will return false anyway, because it sees them as a string. Likewise the ISTEXT function will always return true when used with LEFT or MID for the same reasons. Instead of ISTEXT, you might be able to use some combination of NOT, ISERROR and NUMBERVALUE like so:

check if first char is string:

```
=ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,1)))
```

check if second char is string

```
=ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,2,1)))
```

check if positions 3 and 4 are numbers

```
=NOT(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,3,2))))
```

check is position 5 is hyphen

```
=MID(A1,5,1)="-"
```

check if 6 rightmost positions are numbers

```
=NOT(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1,6))))
```

check if total length is 11

```
=LEN(A1)=11
```

and here are all of them ANDed together:

```
=AND(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,1))),ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,2,1))),NOT(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,3,2)))),MID(A1,5,1)="-",NOT(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1,6)))),LEN(A1)=11)
```

**OR, solution no. 2:**

If you do a lot of text validation in your workbook, you might consider using regular expressions. You have to use VBA to enable it as far as I know though. Insert new module and put this function in:

```vba
Function matchesRegex(stringToBeMatched As String, rgx As String, ByVal ignoreCase As Boolean) As Boolean
    If rgx = vbNullString Then
        matchesRegex = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .ignoreCase = ignoreCase
        .Pattern = rgx
    End With
    matchesRegex = regEx.test(stringToBeMatched)
End Function
```

Then you must enable this reference in Tools -> References:

[image]

And now you can use the matchesRegex function in your workbook like so:

```
=matchesRegex(A1,"\D{2}\d{2}-\d{6}",TRUE)
```

This tiny function does the exact same thing as all those built-in functions above. So if you do a lot of this stuff, I recommend learning regular expressions and using those.

Comment: You have to put commas in the formulas, not semi-colons (could be a language setting). Also it will return *TRUE* for empty cells too: `NOT(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(""))) -> TRUE`

Comment: @XaC I'm so sorry! My environment is setup like this. I usually change it before I post it here but I forgot. I'll correct it. *done

Comment: @XaC as for the empty cell, I don't really think it's a big deal as all these functions will be ANDed together anyway and it does return false on an empty cell then.

Comment: @andrewb I'm away from my PC at the moment, but I just wanted to ask really quick: is there a particular reason why the string checks are separated out to individual characters, whereas the numerical digits are okay consolidated?

Comment: @Arctiic yes. For example "A1" would still evaluate as string, therefore as "TRUE" if you checked both at once, which you do not want I assume. This is because the function depends on the conversion to number failing and it would fail in that case. You don't need to do this with numbers because just a single character anywhere will cause the conversion to fail, therefore correctly evaluating the result as having wrong character in it.

Comment: @andrewb Ah, that makes sense!  I just tried the validation formula right now but it seems to not be working?  Specifically, I entered what *should* qualify as a valid entry but received a stop error for the validation check.  I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but I'm not at home at the moment so I'm using Excel on the Web (I'm on a Chromebook).

Comment: @Arctiic hmm I'm not sure, it is working for me, I double checked by copying the formulas from my answer back to excel but I only have access to Excel 2010. Do you know which one of the 5 formulas is misbehaving or did you join them all together? One problem I just noticed is that for example "aa11-12345" will still be valid because rightmost 6 characters are "-12345" and that is a number... so to make this absolutely 100% correct, some changes would probably be necessary :/ I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @Arctiic I updated the answer with one more formula which checks if total length of the string is 11, which is needed I realized and also put in the whole thing wrapped in one AND so that you can test it more easily. Please do let me know if it works.

Comment: @andrewb Thanks!  I just tested it and unfortunately it still seems to be rejecting valid entries still for some yet (to me) undeterminable reason.  Frankly, I'm a little agitated by the seemingly complete absence of any logging or troubleshooting tools available to address data validation errors, I even went and installed Diagnostics Data Viewer and saw nothing relevant/useful being captured from Excel.  How should I go about narrowing down the cause?

Comment: @Arctiic that's so weird. Can you give me an example of an entry which should be allowed but isn't? It works completely fine for me.

Comment: @andrewb No problem!  Just for the sake of testing, I used PA12-121212.  I've tried several other variants, but none are working.  Can't figure it out, really wish there was something like `logcat` but for Excel lol.

Comment: @Arctiic Tye only thing that comes to my mind right now is that the formula checks for value in "A1". You are validating A1 right? Because if you put this formula as validation in C11 like in your example, it's never going to work. Probably should have mentioned that